# SmartGWT: How to make ListGrid respond to datasource structure chages after adding, updating, removing operatios?

Tags: smartgwt, listgrid

I have a dynamic DataSource and it is bound to a ListGrid. By dynamic understand that its columns depending on data in a database.

So, after insert, update, or remove a line in my ListGrid the datasource structure may change. Then I need to reload the datasource in order to verify if its structure (columns) should be changed. Ergo, the ListGrid must respond to these eventual changes.

For instance, when a new line is added to the database table and consequently listed in the ListGrid, maybe a new column could be displayed toward showing the entire data for that line. If this line is removed, then that new column must be removed.

The problem is that after inserting or removing, even if I call the method responsible of reloading the datasource and destroying and recreating the grid, the columns stay the same. Please, take a look at my code below:

Method for loading the datasource:

```
private void generateNumberRangesDataSourceDynamycally() {

    String appID = AppServiceConstants.APP_ID;
    String className = AppServiceConstants.SCAFACADE_SERVICE_NAME;
    String methodName = AppServiceConstants.METHOD_GETNUMBERRANGES;

    DMI.call(appID, className, methodName, new PAIRPCCallback() {

        @Override
        public void executeRPCCall(RPCResponse response, Object rawData, RPCRequest request) {

            if (response.getStatus() == RPCResponse.STATUS_FAILURE) {

                SC.warn( scatext.error_numberrange_datasource_generation() );

            }

        }

    }, loadNumberRangesDataSource());

}
```

Trigger method that starts the DMI for dynamically loading the datasource:

```
private Object[] loadNumberRangesDataSource() {

    DataSource.load(LUNummernkreiseContent.DYNAMICDS_ID, dataSourceCallbackFunction(), true);

    return new Object[] { AppController.getRequestToken() };

}
```

Callback function for dynamic datasource loading:

```
private Function dataSourceCallbackFunction() {

    final Function function = new Function() {

        @Override
        public void execute() {

            display.getLayout().getGrid().destroy(); // destroying the HTML reference to the component;
            display.getLayout().setGrid( null ); // nullifying the java object

            dsDynamic = DataSource.get( LUNummernkreiseContent.DYNAMICDS_ID );

            if (dsDynamic != null) {

                setupGrid();
                refreshGrid();


            }
        }

    };

    return function;
}
```

Following methods are responsible for setting up the grid and fetching current data:

```
protected void refreshGrid() {

    display.getLayout().getGrid().fetchData( criteria );

}

protected void setupGrid() {

    display.getLayout().getGrid().setDataSource( dsDynamic );

    final HeaderSpan headerSpan = new HeaderSpan(scatext.screen_lunummernkreis_grid_luHeaderSpan(),
            new String[] {LUNummernkreiseContent.START_FIELD, LUNummernkreiseContent.END_FIELD});

    display.getLayout().getGrid().setHeaderSpans( headerSpan );
    display.getLayout().getGrid().getField( LUNummernkreiseContent.START_FIELD ).setTitle( scatext.screen_lunummernkreis_window_spinnerFrom() );
    display.getLayout().getGrid().getField( LUNummernkreiseContent.END_FIELD ).setTitle( scatext.screen_lunummernkreis_window_spinnerTo() );
    display.getLayout().getGrid().getField( LUNummernkreiseContent.DELIVERYTYPE_FIELD ).setTitle( scatext.screen_lunummernkreis_window_comboType() );
    display.getLayout().getGrid().getField( LUNummernkreiseContent.COUNTRYNAME_FIELD ).setTitle( scatext.screen_lunummernkreis_window_comboCountry() );
    display.getLayout().getGrid().getField( LUNummernkreiseContent.COUNTRYCODE_FIELD ).setTitle( scatext.screen_lunummernkreis_grid_columnCountryCode() );

}
```

Any idea? Emphasizing the point: I need that the grid responds to dynamic structural datasource changes, after performing CRUD operation.

Comment: Hi Vitor. I saw [your question](http://forums.smartclient.com/forum/smart-gwt-technical-q-a/239899-how-to-dynamically-generate-grid-columns) also on the SmartGWT forums, and I'd like to give it a try and help you, but it's very difficult without a simpler test case that I can just copy-past to start playing with. Otherwise, being this a complex use case, I think it would be difficult to help you out (as you probably already figured out from the responses Blama and Isomorphic gave you there). Is there any chance you can come up with a simple test case?

Comment: For me carlossierra, the problems is here: DataSource.load(LUNummernkreiseContent.DYNAMICDS_ID, dataSourceCallbackFunction(), true); The callback function is invoked before reload process ends. Please, realize that I am setting forceReload arg as true. But for me the callback is called before reload. For example, if add a line that require a new column in the grid nothing happens, but if add a second line soon after, then the new column appears. JAVADOC says:  If no loading occurs because the requested DataSource(s) are already loaded, a warning is logged and the callback is fired immediately.

Comment: I understand that, but without a simple test case, it will be too time consuming for me to try and replicate your behavior, so that I can debug and inspect to see if I come up with a solution. As I said before, this is a complex use case, and by just looking at it, it's difficult to know what can be going wrong.